# Chain Promises Node.js using Q Not Working

Tags: node.js, events, event-handling

Pretty simple Node.js (console app) code:

```
var request = require("request");
var q = require("q");
var data = new Object();
var deferred = new q.defer();

var url1 = "https://www.google.com"
var url2 = "https://www.yahoo.com"
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

console.log('begin data1');
requestData(url1) //Promises seem to be working fine here
    .then(function () { console.log('finished data1'); }) //At this point, we go back to async, and everything from here down executes at the same time.
    .then(function () { console.log('begin data2'); })
    .then(function () { requestData(url2); }) //Expected behavior is that it should pause here, and execute everything below after the request is complete.
    .then(function () { console.log('finished data2'); })
    .then(function () { console.log(data); })
    .then(function () { console.log('finished write2'); })
    .then(function () { console.log('operation completed!'); });

function requestData(url) {
    console.log(url);
    data = new Object();
    console.log(data);
    deferred = new q.defer();
    console.log(deferred);
    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, obj) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            data = obj;
            deferred.resolve();
            console.log(deferred);
        } else {
            console.log('err');
        }
    });  
   return deferred.promise;
}
```

The problem is after the first `.then` statement, everything executes asynchronously. I want the second time I run 'requestData' call to be synchronous like the first.

Pardon my console logs for debugging purposes.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are not returning a promise in the `then` methods.

Try this:

```
...something.then(function() {  
        return requestData(url2);
}).then(function() { //called after requestData ended});
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Simple. Thanks!